Does this 3 dot symbol in these lyrics have any special meaning? Therefore symbol, ∴

From the song 恥ずかしいか、青春は. The symbol appears in these lyrics, and the singer does pause between the two words.
This may not even be a Japanese thing, as the symbol is the "therefore" symbol, ∴. It DOES technically make sense here, as it is a ground of unexplored adventure (未開拓冒険), so therefore it will be filled with curiosity (好奇心旺盛). However, I just want to make sure: is this just a peculiar symbol use, or does it have actual punctual merit in Japanese beyond some specialized use from the song-writer?

The ∴ symbol itself is widely recognized by high school students and above. It's read as ゆえに or したがって, and means the same thing as in English ("thus/therefore"). In this case, you can read it "未開拓冒険地帯 aka 好奇心旺盛時代" or "未開拓冒険地帯 which means 好奇心旺盛時代".
This symbol is almost never used outside mathematical contexts, but since another math symbol (≒) is used later in the lyrics, it's clear that the authors used them deliberately.

I will add this note: ≒ is the same as ≈.
